# Getting up and running with boost

Tags: windows, cygwin

So I have cygwin installed and up and running. I can change directories, whole nine yards.

I have run the following [test](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/cygwin/part3/)  and it works.

NOTE:

```
C:\cygwin\
```

and

```
C:\cygwin\boost_1_53_0
```

also in my path system environment variable I have:

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b Student\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b Student\bin\win32;C:\cygwin\bin

Now - when I try and run the following: ([Boost TUtorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html)) bootstrap.cmd on a windows machine I get the following error;

```
### "Could not find a suitable toolset."
###
### You can specify the toolset as the argument, i.e.:
###     .\build.bat msvc
###
### Toolsets supported by this script are: borland, como, gcc, gcc-nocygwin,
###     intel-win32, metrowerks, mingw, msvc, vc7, vc8, vc9, vc10, vc11
###
```

Please any help would be fantastic

Comment: Do you have `gcc` installed? BTW prebuilt-binaries are available from boost, therefore you just need to copy those header files into your `include` directory and download those binary lib files you need. (You need not build **boost** yourself on cygwin)

Comment: Yes I have tested gcc with the hello.cpp test available.